# Updating value object in domain object. Assign reference from outside

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

I have domain object User which contains simple value object 'Contact'. Contact contains only getters without setters.

```
public class User {
    private Contact contact;
// other methods and fields
}

public class Contact {
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private String fax;
// and geters
}
```

I need to  update user's contact. I have two ways to do this, but I don't know which is better. Does domain object should allow to assign reference from outside? But on other hand creating new object maybe is overuse.

```
public void updateContact(Contact newContact) {
    this.contact = newContact;
}

public void updateContact(Contact newContact) {
    this.contact = new Contact(newContact.getEmail(), newContact.getFax(), newContact.getPhone());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you're not dealing with a soft or weak reference, so there is no reason to assume that the instance of `newContact` being passed cannot be retained.  More importantly, there are no setters on `Contact`, which strongly implies that `Contact` is immutable.  This isn't to say it *can't* be forcibly changed, though doing so would almost certainly be wrong.

Therefore, if you assume `Contact` is immutable, you would not be at fault for doing so, and you should be safe simply assigning your contact to `newContact` being passed (your first `updateContact` method).